# Name not reflected when generating nla strip with Python as strips.new() method

Tags: python, scripting, nla-editor

I looked at the api document and expected the name parameter of the strips.new() method to be reflected in the name of the strip, but it wasn't. Did I misunderstand anything? What is the purpose of the name parameter of the strips.new() method?

[image]

[image]

---

I tried to explicitly indicate the parameter name, but it didn't reflect the name either.
[image]

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't seem to work. I added the test contents to the body.

Comment: IIRC has been asked before it is being given the name of the assigned action.   Can rename the action, eg name the action "Walk"  and first strip with that action will also  be "Walk" or (as suggested above by G) rename the strip after creating.

Comment: _ie_  `strip.name = "Foo"`

Comment: "What is the purpose of the name parameter" [Nothing, it's unused](https://github.com/sobotka/blender/blob/7b524d9b710f18dc4539a97de7fad7a760565757/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_nla.c#L393).

Comment: Oh wow.. I didn't expect to see the C code. I feel like I've swallowed a red pill.